# Can't Raise negative numbers to a fractional power

Tags: python

```
x1 = -b + (b **2 - 4*a*c) ** 0.5
x2 = x1 / (2 * a)
```

My program takes user input and solves the quadratic function. However it is unable to process negative numbers, and I get the fractional power error. I want to know how to make it so that my program can accept negative numbers and still give correct answers.

I tried following but it doesn't give me an output, just blank lines:

```
x1 = -b + (b **2 - 4*a*c+0j) ** 0.5
x2 = x1 / (2 * a)
```

Comment: The 1/2th power (square root) of a negative number is a complex number. See [`cmath` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cmath.html) for working with complex numbers.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that negative bases and fractional powers may be ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

you should work with complex numbers for this purpose use cmath:

```
import cmath
x1 = -b + cmath.sqrt(b **2 - 4*a*c)
x2 = x1 / (2 * a)
```

Comment: I tried this but it is still giving me blank outputs.

Comment: import sys
import math 
import cmath
a = input('Please input a: ')
b = input('Please input b: ')
c = input('Please input c: ')

x1 = -b + cmath.sqrt(b **2 - 4*a*c)
x2 = x1 / (2 * a)

x3 = -b + cmath.sqrt(b **2 - 4*a*c)
x4 = x3 / (2 * a)

print (x2)
print (x4)

Comment: @Grim There is error `ac` should be `a*c`. Also which python are you using?

Comment: I'm using 2.7, and I fixed the ac issue but the problem still persists. Should I use :

Comment: Sorry accidentally pressed enter but should I use cmath.exp instead of cmath.sqrt

Comment: @Grim Whis this code http://paste.ofcode.org/AqVAN6zCr2t8FdtnA5KaHk I got next result http://paste.ofcode.org/VLxtu3ZsqqnL6TjKQAkug6 . You can't you cmath.exp in this case.

Comment: I think I know what the problem is. I'm using an app on my iPad called pythoni to run my code. I am currently in school and don't have access to a computer. Could you tell me the answer you get if a = 1 b = -4 c = -3

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help it seems like I need to learn more and keep working at the problem.